# Compare multiple conditions sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have two table which shows below data

table 1

```
Number Time  CID
 001    24    1
 002    12    1
 003    25    2
 004    7     2
```

range table 2

```
 Time1 Time2  CID   PhoneNumber
 7      12    1      333
 24     99    null   300 
 7      24    null   301
 7      12     2     345
```

required result

```
 Number Time  PhoneNumber
 001    24    300
 001    24    301
 002    12    333
 002    12    301
 003    25    300
 004    7     345
 004    7     301
```

in range table CID "NULL" means check range of time and all CID is include. where CID value is available compare with CID in table 1.

Comment: What is the link between the two tables? Why are you trying to join them that way? It's a good start that you provided what you want the end result to look like, but what is the problem that you are solving? And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You could `join` 2 tables like this

```
select t1.Number, t1.Time, t2.PhoneNumber
from Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.Time between t2.Time1 and t2.Time2 
WHERE t1.CID = t2.CID or t2.CID is null
ORDER BY t1.Number
```

Demo link: http://rextester.com/IDKHA81401

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
tb1.Number
,tb1.[Time]
,tb2.PhoneNumber
FROM table1 tb1
INNER JOIN table2 tb2 ON tb1.CID = ISNULL(tb2.CID, tb1.CID) 
AND tb1.[Time] BETWEEN tb2.[Time1] AND tb2.[Time2]
ORDER BY tb1.Number
```

I hope it will work for you.